# how to create self incresing number in xsl:if

Tags: xslt, numbers

I have an issue, I need to test if field exist, and if its not exist, I need to increase number inside if, example:

```
....
<xsl:for-each select="InvoiceItem/InvoiceItemGroup/ItemEntry/Accounting/JournalEntry/CostObjective">
<xsl:if test="not(DIM06)">
<xsl:value-of select="value of number ++"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
....
```

The problem is, that `position()` doesnt work in this way. Because In output i get: 1,2,4,5... Instead of that, I need 1,2,3,4.

Hope you understand what I need, and hope you will help me find a solution.

Comment: You can probably use xsl:number, but it's hard to say without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

`position()` is based on the position of the node in the list of nodes selected, not the position in the original document tree.

Assuming you don't want to do anything with the items with no `DIM06` node, you need to make the condition part of the `xsl:for-each` instead, so only those nodes are selected in the first place

```
<xsl:for-each select="InvoiceItem/InvoiceItemGroup/ItemEntry/Accounting/JournalEntry/CostObjective[not(DIM06)]">
  <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day, bless you :)